# Connect to my server from outside my network securely

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, ipsec, cisco-router

I have a LAN with computers connected to server, what I need to do is connecting PC  to this server securely from another location.

My network structure is described in the image attached and needs to connect PC0 with server shown on the image.

[image]

My server OS is windows server 2008 and PC0 OS is windows 7 ultimate,
the purpose of connection is to run oracle software from PC0 but the database located at server.

I already search in internet I found some solutions regarding VPN client Server or split tunnelling or Easy VPN, but I actually not understand how to proceed that because I don't have strong knowledge in networks.

Can any one help me with clear example? I will be pleased for that, because I have to link that PC as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

and sorry of my bad English

--EDIT

There was already exist vpn connection between warehouse PC and server with static IP set in both server and warehouse, 
but now I have to connect PC0 to the server , PC0 connected to normal WiFi router not Cisco 800, what the configurations i need,

Comment: Welcome to superuser! Would you please edit your question and provide the information about the server - what OS it has installed, what version? And also about the PC0 - what OS it has, what version and etc.. What access do you have to both of them, is it administrative?

Comment: thanks  @Fanatique for reply, I already update Question, hope that what you mean.

Comment: If you have already setup your ASA to be able to reach the Server as shown in n/w topology, then should be all set. PC0 when connected to ASA, should be able to reach the Server.

Comment: thanks @Mahesh for replay, I update the question with some details may clear the idea, the current network topology was already exist before I came to the company, Now just i need to connect PC0 to the network.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but still worth mentioning: if you are trying to do these kinds of things in a professional environment, it's probably wise to get professional help for this. If you don't know what you're doing, you could easily expose your database to the entire internet, potentially causing all kinds of harm. A professional could set this up for you in 1-2 hours.

Comment: Thanks @mtak for your reply, although your reply was right but actually made me disappointed, I need to learn how to do that my self with help of professionals if possible, I am specialist in programming but i have  little knowledge in network. Thats why I posted my case in this site.

Comment: I agree with what @mtak suggested. Besides that, isn't your ASA publicly reachable by default ? It is not usual to have a ASA in production environment which is not publicly reachable, unless having a strong reason for such a setup.